# call_user_func() not catching errors

Tags: php, error-handling

**PHP**: 7.13

There is this standard PHP method, which is `call_user_func()`.

The documentations says:

> @return mixed the function result, or false on error.

Here is a small code snippet to test behaviour on error:

```php
function foo() {
    throw new ErrorException('foo');
}

$result = call_user_func('foo');

echo "Result: '$result' \n";
```

I expected `call_user_func()` to catch the `Error` and return `false`, but instead this program just fails with:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: foo in /Users/hubert/learn/php/projects/first/main.php:3 Stack trace:
#0 /Users/hubert/learn/php/projects/first/main.php(6): foo()
#1 {main}   thrown in /Users/hubert/learn/php/projects/first/main.php on line 3

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Why is that?
How to see the error catching in action?

Comment: The function does not return, it throws an Exception. So you need to try/catch.

Comment: It will return false if it fails to do the task you give it(i.e. no function exists).

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/call_user_func) but the [PhpStorm Stubs](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/standard/standard_4.php). I think they're just wrong or outdated.

Comment: Just wrong, I'd say: https://3v4l.org/PODVV - In any case, I would assume that return values would only apply to function's own work, it doesn't seem reasonable for a random function to mess with  exception handling.

Comment: @NigelRen can you please add this as the answer? Actually it is the case. It doesn't handle errors thrown by the called methods. And unfortunately is not explained.
@A

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you are right, it is from PhpStorm Stubs. I wasn't accurate enough. Do I understand correctly that the behaviour in PHP 8 has been changed in comparison to PHP 7 in case of non-existing methods?

Answer (score 1):

**call_user_func** calls the callback given by the first parameter. It doesn't catch the error. You should use try/catch inside the function for error catching.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the documentation for the function says...

> @return mixed — the function result, or false on error.

I think the issue is what it means that the function returns *false on error*.

Your example runs a function, so the method actually succeeds in calling the method, the result of the method is that it throws an exception.

Not sure how you would get this to fail as I've tried various things (no arguments, invalid function name) and they all throw specific errors to say what is happening.